# Is it possible to name an AspectJ-declared warning?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I use `declare error` and `declare warning` to enforce some policies; but in some specific cases I would like to get rid of the warning.
Is there a way I can **name the declared warning** so that I can use `@SuppressWarning` ?

Else I see a solution but it doesn't satisfy me: define a custom `@SuppressXxxPolicyWarning` annotation and use it to restrict the `declare warning` pointcut.

Answer (score 2):

You may use @SuppressAjWarnings annotation with a warning declaration as exemplified below.

```
declare warning : execution(!@SuppressAjWarnings * *.badMethodName(..)) : 
    "Your warning message.";
```

Comment: That is the same idea as the custom `@SuppressXxxPolicyWarning` annotation…